# Auto Pull and Sort Data in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I have a table of debts (Name, rank, desc, balance, FMV, IR, and Pay/Mo).  I want to be able to enter the debt information in this table (let's call it Table 1) and then automatically have that data populate in a different table (let's call it Table 2) auto sorted by ascending debt value.  I have only 30 debts allowed in my table.  Any of the debts that are left blank in Table 1 I want to ignore and not pull into Table 2. Right now I'm pulling using a combination of VLOOKUP `=VLOOKUP(1,$I$9:$N$41,3,0)` and RANK `=RANK(K9,K9:K41,1)` (samples of course) but that leaves me with a bunch of #N/A when I have duplicate Ranks (which I'm trying to avoid).  Here are my tables:

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

I need some help here.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started here are a few high level notes on how to accomplish what you are asking for.

1. Look into Worksheet Change events. Use this technique to detect when you change a cell in Table 1 (adding or removing debts). This will trigger the macro that will update Table 2.

Once you detect a change in Table 1 the following should happen:

2. Wipe out all data from Table 2.
3. Loop thru all the debts in Table 1 and write the cell values to Table 2 (debts).
4. Reorganize the data in Table 2.

Since you manipulating the data in vba I would steer away from using worksheet functions like "vlookup" and others in Table 2. You won't need any worksheet functions. Your end product, Table 2, will appear like you manually typed-in the data.

Comment: I haven't used VBA yet, but thought it might be useful. Would you happen to know some good sources for me to get my head wrapped around it?

Comment: stackoverflow is my go to source, so you're in the right spot, but you need to know what to ask. If you've never coded before then starting out will be quite rough. You tagged your question with excel-vba so I thought you might have some background knowledge. You can record macro's in excel and then view the vba code generated by the recorder in the vba editor (ALT+F11). This is a good place to start. The painful thing for beginners using vba is that Excel's vba editor does not have auto-completion or auto-formatting. Good luck.